# Frequency of a load curve signal

Tags: signal, low-pass, fft

I have measured a charge and discharge curve of a capacitor with resistor and I want to calculate the frequency of this signal (for a low pass filter). Am I on the right way if I calculate 1 divided by time constant for the signal frequency? Or should I use  fft?

Comment: Can you add your collected data to your question?

Comment: Is row data enough?

Comment: You need to add whatever data you think will help folks understand what you are trying to do. I would add a simple circuit sketch too.